# How to tell if a OrbBasic program is running

Tags: sphero-api

Is there a way to see if there is currently a OrbBasic program running on Sphero. I'm working on an app for cats and I want to check whether a orbbasic program is running when i start my app.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no API call to determine if there is a program running. If you just need to make sure a program is running, I suggest sending an abort call and then send down the program you want to run.